# Firebase: Authentication (users) shared between multiple otherwise independent Firebase client apps

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am evaluating Firebase as a solution for a suite of semi-independent products (apps). I see **Authentication** as the only aspect to be shared between these apps, the rest of the Firebase functionality (Realtime Database, Analytics etc.) should be individual. Is there any way to achieve this now or do you know if this is somehow on a short or mid term roadmap?

Just to be clear why sharing a user identity between those apps is important. I would like to analyse data produced by the same user in one app to give him/her a specific user experience in another app.

**P.S.** It looks like currently it's impossible to do (unless I'm missing something), but perhaps it is planned and will soon be available...

Comment: This question is unclear. You want to share authentication between your apps but the rest of the data should be individual. What's preventing that from happening? Data within Firebase can be as shared or as individual as you design it for. Maybe updating and clarifying the question would help.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Jay. I want these apps be totally independent as they are going to be developed by different teams. Making database security rules complex to ensure that app1 cannot change the data in used by app2 is not an option for me.

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue. You can craft a fairly straightforward security rule in firebase that would, for example, enable user1 to access data from app1, but not allow that user to access data from app2. Are all the apps backed by Firebase as their database? If they are then the user1 would need to access data from both app1 and app2. You can see where the question is open ended.

Comment: For me this is about an isolation. Currently I'm evaluating Firebase as a Authentication platform for the whole company where different teams can potentially work on very different products up to the point that they should not be able to touch (and potentially break) each other's configurations.

Comment: See my above comment *enable user1 to access data from app1, but not allow that user to access data from app2*. Doesn't that answer the question?

Comment: A clear definition of 'user sharing' would be helpful to understand the question. Assuming a user creates an email + password account in app1, can the user login into app2 using the email+password? When you said 'It looks like currently it's impossible to do so', please list the API input/output you would like to see but missing from Firebase.

Comment: @JinLiu Yes, I'd like the user registered in *app1* being able to login into *app2*, but other than that the apps should be totally independent. I'm not sure it's about API, as I don't think Firebase lacks something. It's more about configuration of projects in Firebase console. It's like having a Workspace to define Authentication configuration and inside of this workspace to have projects where developers can configure the rest of the Firebase functionality.

Comment: @Jay, app1 doesn't know about app2 and vice versa and many other apps. They should be totally isolated and developed by different teams. The only thing they need to share from the get-go is users. This is what my question is about. Please suggest me ways to rewrite it to narrow the scope as I really don't see it as too broad. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can easily do what you are asking to do with Firebase rules. They can be easily set up to allow users of App1 to only access App1. Users of App2 to access only App2 etc. It's still unclear as to what's preventing that from happening (as I mentioned previously).

Comment: @Jay This creates a problem of all developers accessing and changing security rules for the very complex Firebase database which can go very wrong. Also, could you please share a link explaining how to do that based on the app? In addition to that the rest of Firebase functionality will also be shared between all the apps which is something I would also try to avoid.

Comment: You can do that as well... limiting (any) access to the database to certain users is easy. Also, there should be no reason to change the security rules once they are set. The additional comments are why the question was put on hold - a lot of info has been added that could (should) have been included up front. So far, nothing added changes that Firebase can handle it - you just need to come up with a clear plan for who has access to what and then write some code and implement the rules. Maybe you're overthinking it? Give it a whirl and let us know when you get stuck or can't make it work!